# jQuery AJAX call not exiting when there is no response data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: application.common.relativePath + '/persons/search/',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        // parameters name-value pairs to be passed
        data: {
            forename: forename,
            surname: surname,
            checkEmployee: false
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // no response data
            if (!data) {
                return; // THIS IS THE PROBLEM.
            }

            // code executed if there is a response.
        }
 });
```

When there is no response data, the AJAX function should exit, hence the use of the `return` statement. However, what I am finding is that even if there is no response data (`data` is null), the code below gets executed which means that the `return` statement is not being called to break out of the jQuery AJAX call.

Can anyone please help me to break out of the AJAX call if there is no data response.

Comment: How do you know it is not exiting? Have you checked network request on console? Request might not be completed

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL I have checked the network request on my JavaScript browser console and it does attempt the AJAX request. The request does complete.

Comment: And it finishes? Have you seen 200 response?

Comment: Yes, I get a Green 200 OK status code

Comment: So is condition `if (!data)` reached? I guess no. So what output `console.log(data);` ??? FYI, `"null" != null`

Comment: Why don't you use a flag in the returned data? Something like `data.hasContent`. The current logic is so fragile.

Comment: It's not my code. It's an existing codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Ajax call which ends in Success will ALWAYS return data. If the server has no data to return, it will return an empty object of Datatype (in this case Json). you'll have to check if the Json object contains data.

Comment: So using jQuery: `if($.isEmptyObject( data )) return;`

Comment: Yes, it returns [] if no data is returned from the server.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is, always return response flag from your service like;

in your controller(PHP),

```
$res = array(
    "status" => true,
    "data" => "Successfuly saved"
);
echo json_encode($res);
```

And in your js, check;

```
success: function(data) {
    // no response data
    if (data.status == true) {
        // success
    } else {
        // error
    }
}
```

If you do not use status like something, you can check like;

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        // success
    } else {
        // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the `success` method in AJAX call will called if the *request* (not anything, related to the returned data) succeeds.

The function gets passed *three* arguments:

- the data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter;
- a string describing the status;
- and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest)

It appears, that your server returns data, even if it is an empty string, or just empty space (ASCII code 32). However if this is the case, then `if (!data)` will not be `false`. Try different compartment and/or use all 3 parameters of the `success` method to see what's inside of them.